# How organize the registration form to properly handle this 4 scenarios?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a registration form below for a user register in a congress. The user can register only him in the congress but also other participants.  There are 4 different scenarios for the registration. So the registration form needs to handle this 4 different scenarios. But its not working, only the scenario 1 and 2 and 4 are working fine. The scenario 3 is not working properly.

Do you know how to achieve a registration form that supports this 4 scenarios?

**The scenario 1 is when: (the only scenario that is working fine)**

- there are two ticket types for the congress, for example: "ticket type 1" and "ticket type 2"
- the ticket type "ticket type 1" has 1 or more custom question(s) associated, for example, "Whats your phone?" and the ticket type "ticket type 2" dont have any custom question associated
- The all_participants column in the congresses table is "1" which means that is necessary to collect info (name and surname) of each participant that the user is registering
- Diagram to demonstrate how this scenario should be:

[image]

**The scenario 2 is when:**

- there are two ticket types for the congress, for example: "ticket type 1" and "ticket type 2"
- the ticket type "ticket type t1" and "ticket type 2" dont have any custom question associated
- all participants is "1" which means that is necessary to collect info of each participant
- Diagram to demonstrate how this scenario should be:

[image]

**The scenario 3 is when:**

- there are two ticket types for the congress, for example: "ticket type 1" and "ticket type 2"
- the ticket type "ticket type 1" has a custom question associated "Whats your phone?", the ticket type "ticket type 2" dont have any custom question associated
- all participants is "0" which means that is not necessary to collect info (name and surname) of each participant
- Diagram to demonstrate how this scenario should be:
  [image]

**The scenario 4 is when:**

- there are two ticket types for the congress, for example: "ticket type 1" and "ticket type 2"
- the ticket types "ticket type 1" and "ticket type 2" dont have any custom question associated
- all participants is "0" which means that is not necessary to collect info (name and surname) of each participant
- Diagram to demonstrate how this scenario should be:
  [image]

The selected tickets from the previous page are available in the variable "`$selectedTypes`".

The registration form that I have for now in the registration.blade.php is like below:

```
<form method="post" id="step1formfree" action="">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @if (!is_null($allParticipants) && is_int($allParticipants))
        @if($allParticipants == 1)
            <p>Please fill all fields. Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.</p>
        @else
            <p>Is not necessary additional info. Your tickets will be send to <b>{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.</p>
        @endif

        <span id="userData" data-name="{{ auth()->user()->name }}" data-surname="{{ auth()->user()->surname }}"></span>

        @foreach($selectedRtypes as $k => $selectedRtype)
            //{{dd($selectedRtype)}}
            @foreach(range(1,$selectedRtype['quantity']) as $val)
                @if($allParticipants == 1)
                    <h6>Participant - {{$val}} - {{$k}}</h6>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="fill_auth_info{{ $val }}" data-id="{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}"name="fill_with_auth_info">
                        <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="fill_auth_info{{ $val }}">
                            <span class="mr-auto">Fill with auth user info.</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                        <label for="name{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                        <input type="text"  id="name{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                        <label for="surname{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="surname{{ $k }}_{{ $val }}" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                    </div>
                    @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                                   class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                            <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                                   value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    <input type="hidden" value="foo" name="participant_name[]"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="bar" name="participant_surname[]"/>
                @endif
                <input type="hidden" name="rtypes[]" value="{{ $selectedRtype['id'] }}"/>
            @endforeach
                    <div class="form-group">
            @if ($allParticipants == 0)
                @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                               class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                               value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif
    <input type="submit" href="#step2"
           id="goToStep2Free" class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
</form>
```

The "`{{dd($selectedRtype)}}`" if there are no custom questions and were selected 2 tickets of the same ticket type shows:

```
array:6 [▼
  "quantity" => "2"
  "price" => 0
  "subtotal" => 0
  "total" => 0
  "questions" => Collection {#232 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  "id" => 1
]
```

If there area custom questions shows:

```
array:6 [▼
  "quantity" => "1"
  "price" => 0
  "subtotal" => 0
  "total" => 0
  "questions" => Collection {#232 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => Question {#233 ▼
        #fillable: array:3 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: null
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:6 [▶]
        #original: array:9 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "question" => "What is your phone?"
          "type" => "text"
          "congress_id" => 1
          "created_at" => "2018-05-06 12:24:41"
          "updated_at" => "2018-05-06 12:24:41"
          "pivot_registration_type_id" => 1
          "pivot_question_id" => 1
          "pivot_required" => 1
        ]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: array:1 [▶]
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
    ]
  }
  "id" => 1
]
```

Relationships relevant for the question:

```
1 to many between Congresses and Registrations
1 to many between Congresses and TicketTypes
1 to many between Registrations and Participants
1 to many between TicketTypes and Participants
1 to many between Participants and Answers
1 to many between Questions and Answers
Many to Many between TicketTypes and Questions
1 to many between Congresses and Questions
```

Answer (score 0):

well you have not enough description in your question but i thing that is because of this line:

```
<h6>Participant - 1 - {{$test}}</h6>
```

this line has no condition and will repeat in the whole loop
that`s because you take tow.
i hope it help.

Comment: Thanks, but like that that part "<h6>Participant - 1 - {{$test}}</h6>" dont appear twice if the user selected 2 tickets in the previous page but the custom question "Whats your phone?" is appearing twice, but it should only appear once for only the user that is doing the registration to answer.

Comment: oh, i told you that you did not send enough code and i just say that with these information.

Comment: I update the question with a digram showing the issue, the code of the registration form is the code that is in the question.